# How to use a ISO7816 smartcard to authenticate in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have a smartcard that stores the user credentials and want to use this information to authenticate in Bluemix.

I suppose I could use the SSO service in bluemi but it seems that I need to program the federation routine. Any idea?